# Phonegap How to open Spotify url in Spotify app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build, spotify

I need to know How to open Spotify url in Spotify native app in Android and iOS. The example for opening facebook is

```
if(device.platform == "Android"){
    scheme = "com.facebook.katana";
}else if(device.platform == "iOS"){
    scheme = "fb://";
}
window.open(url, "_system");
```

Comment: first of all you should know the spotify package name for android and the url scheme for ios

Comment: Yes that is what i need to know, i have searched but haven't found anything

Comment: You are not good at searching then: ios http://handleopenurl.com/search?scheme=spotify android https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spotify.music

Comment: Thanks for the links and yes i am new to phonegap and mobile development. So for opening a track in the app the url will be
http://spotify:track:0FMhMAFPLg8EljnROSoVnj
is that right ?

Answer (score -1):

RTFM
Use *inAppBrowser*
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

Stackexchange wants more words in my message.